# Error connecting to server. " Failed to startup SSH: Connection refused "

Tags: ssh, remote-access

I'm trying to get into my Ubuntu 14.04 files remotely from my laptop via wired connection but I keep getting " Failed to startup SSH session: Connection refused ", I have setup the samba shared folders with full access to everyone yet I am still getting this, pls help.

Answer (score 2):

The error you get means you need to run `SSH` server.
I do not kow what you are trying to do, but if you want it not to give you that error you will need to install ssh server, use the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Comment: that did the trick, but I had installed it before but wasn't working, perhaps something got messed up with other installs, thanks